# How to set a background color to cells in a multiindex table?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this multiindex column df:

```
None         INT        INT        INT        PP         PP         PP                       
DATE      2021-12-01 2021-12-02 2021-12-03 2021-12-04 2021-12-05 2021-12-06
0            1.0        0.0        2.0        2.0        4.0        2.0
1            NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2            0.0        0.0        2.0        0.0        3.0        4.0
3            0.0        2.0        2.0        2.0        3.0        2.0
4            0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
5            0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
6            0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
7            2.0        1.0        0.0        1.0        2.0        0.0
8            NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
9            0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
```

I want to give a background color style to only values in 'PP' columns (and export to Excel) based on their values (white to values 0, lightgray to values 1, etc.). So I have in mind this:

```
###############################################################################
n=len(df.columns)
def colors_excel(s):
    
    if s.PP == 0:
        return ['background-color: white']*n
    elif s.PP == 1:
        return ['background-color: lightgray']*n
    elif s.PP == 2:
        return ['background-color: gray']*n
    elif s.PP == 3:
        return ['background-color: yellow']*n
    elif s.PP == 4:
        return ['background-color: orange']*n
    elif s.PP == 5:
        return ['background-color: red']*n
    else:
        return ['background-color: black']*n 
###############################################################################
exceldata=df.style.apply(colors_excel, axis=0)

exceldata.to_excel('ROUTE/name_of_thefile.xlsx',
                     engine='openpyxl', index=True)
```

But this doesn't work in a multiindex column. And I don't want to drop the date of the multiindex columns. How can I solve this?

Here is another example of what I expect to get:

[image]

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Fixed Cell Format

Let's prepare the data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = '''None         INT        INT        INT        PP         PP         PP                       
DATE      2021-12-01 2021-12-02 2021-12-03 2021-12-04 2021-12-05 2021-12-06
0            1.0        0.0        2.0        2.0        4.0        2.0
1            NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2            0.0        0.0        2.0        0.0        3.0        4.0
3            0.0        2.0        2.0        2.0        3.0        2.0
4            0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
5            0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        5.0        0.0
6            0.0        0.0        0.0        6.0        0.0        0.0
7            2.0        1.0        0.0        1.0        2.0        0.0
8            NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
9            0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0        0.0
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', header=[0,1], index_col=0)
```

In order to replace values with the specified colors, I'd use a dictionary and `applymap` method:

```
colors = {
    0: 'white',
    1: 'lightgray',
    2: 'gray',
    3: 'yellow',
    4: 'orange',
    5: 'red'
}

default_color = 'black'
get_color = lambda x: colors.get(x, default_color)
color_map = lambda df: 'background-color: ' + df.applymap(get_color).values + ';'
```

In the last line I used `.values` to switch form `DataFrame` to `numpy.ndarray` to avoid any mismatch with index or column labels.

Next, in the styler I'd use `apply` with:

- `color_map` as a function,
- `axis=None` to pass a frame as an argument to `color_map`,
- and `subset='PP'` to restrict the whole frame to those with *PP* in headers:

```
exceldata = df.style.apply(color_map, subset='PP', axis=None)
exceldata.to_excel('file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=True)
```

#### Conditional Format

As far as data are formatted conditionaly, it seems natural to use conditional formattig in a Excel file. This can be handy if we are going to continue working with data in Excel. The way how to do this depends on the engine we use (openpyxl, xlsxwriter, etc.).

Let's stick to `openpyxl`:

```
file = 'test.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Data')
```

Now, before closing `writer` we have to assing a conditional formatting. For this we need to find out the upper left and lower right corner of the range where `df.PP` is placed. Note that by default a line for index naming will be placed between headers and data. So the row where data start is `(df.columns.nlevels + 1) + 1`:

```
row_start = df.columns.nlevels + 2
row_end = row_start + len(df) - 1
```

As for the columns, we could use sort of `df.columns.get_level_values(0) == 'PP'` to find columns with *PP* in headers, or something like `df.columns.get_loc('PP')` which in this case will return a slice from 3rd to 6th column. Let's do it with `get_loc`:

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

col_slice = df.columns.get_loc('PP')
col_start = get_column_letter(col_slice.start + 2)
col_end = get_column_letter(col_slice.stop + 1)

range_str = f'{col_start}{row_start}:{col_end}{row_end}'
```

Here:

- `range_str` is an address of `df.PP` data at the worksheet, sort of `'E4:G13'`;
- `col_xlise.start + 2`: we add +1 because Excel starts indexing of columns from 1, and +1 because the first column is occupied by indices;
- `col_slice.stop + 1`: plus 2 for the same reason as previously, and minus 1 because the `.stop` value in a slice is an unreachable limit, i.e. the real last value in this slice is `col_slise.stop - 1`.

Now we can add conditional formats:

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import CellIsRule

BLACK = '010101'
colors = {
    '""': BLACK,     # black for blank cells    
    '0': "FFFFFF",   # white
    '1': "CCCCCC",   # lightgray
    '2': "999999",   # gray
    '3': "FFFF00",   # yellow
    '4': "FFCC00",   # orange
    '5': "FF0000",   # red
}

colors = {k: PatternFill(bgColor=v, fill_type='solid') for k, v in colors.items()}

for value, color in colors.items():
    sheet.conditional_formatting.add(
        range_str,
        CellIsRule('equal', formula=[value], stopIfTrue=True, fill=color),
    )
    
sheet.conditional_formatting.add(
    range_str,
    CellIsRule('notBetween', formula=['0','5'], stopIfTrue=True, 
               fill=PatternFill(bgColor=BLACK, fill_type='solid'), 
               font=Font(color='FFFFFF')),
)
```

Notes:

- blank cells are equal to zero in Excel, so we have to check them first (before comparing with 0) by comparing to empty string;
- the black color `"0x000000"` is treated by openpyxl as white (don't know why), so we have to define it as *almost* black;
- at the end we add an additional rule for values out of the interval [0, 5]; to make this more specific like `not in the list [0,1,2,3,4,5]` we have to come up with some other rule.

#### Full Code

*Part 1*

```
colors = {
    0: 'white',
    1: 'lightgray',
    2: 'gray',
    3: 'yellow',
    4: 'orange',
    5: 'red'
}

default_color = 'black'
get_color = lambda x: colors.get(x, default_color)
color_map = lambda df: 'background-color: ' + df.applymap(get_color).values + ';'

exceldata = df.style.apply(color_map, subset='PP', axis=None)
exceldata.to_excel('file.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=True)
```

*Part 2*

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Font
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import CellIsRule


file = 'test.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Data')

book = writer.book
sheet = book['Data']

row_start = df.columns.nlevels + 2
row_end = row_start + len(df) - 1
col_slice = df.columns.get_loc('PP')
col_start = get_column_letter(col_slice.start + 2)
col_end = get_column_letter(col_slice.stop + 1)
range_str = f'{col_start}{row_start}:{col_end}{row_end}'

BLACK = '010101'
colors = {
    '""': BLACK,     # black for blank cells    
    '0': "FFFFFF",   # white
    '1': "CCCCCC",   # lightgray
    '2': "999999",   # gray
    '3': "FFFF00",   # yellow
    '4': "FFCC00",   # orange
    '5': "FF0000",   # red
}
colors = {k: PatternFill(bgColor=v, fill_type='solid') for k, v in colors.items()}

for value, color in colors.items():
    sheet.conditional_formatting.add(
        range_str,
        CellIsRule('equal', formula=[value], stopIfTrue=True, fill=color),
    )

sheet.conditional_formatting.add(
    range_str,
    CellIsRule('notBetween', formula=['0','5'], stopIfTrue=True, 
               fill=PatternFill(bgColor=BLACK, fill_type='solid'), 
               font=Font(color='FFFFFF')),
)

writer.close()
```

---

python: 3.10.7
pandas: 1.5.1
openpyxl: 3.0.10

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Styler.apply(func, axis=None, subset)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) to get a DataFrame with valid index and columns labels considering `subset`:

```py
def highlight_cols(df):
    color = pd.DataFrame().reindex_like(df.droplevel(0, axis=1))
    colors = ['yellow', 'lightgray', 'gray']

    color = color.fillna(f'background-color: {colors[-1]}')
    for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns.get_level_values(1)):
        if idx < len(colors) - 1:
            color = color.mask(df.eq(idx).values, f'background-color: {colors[idx]}')

    return color.values


idx = pd.IndexSlice
style = df.style.apply(highlight_cols, axis=None, subset=idx[:, idx['PP', :]])
style.to_excel('74075209.xlsx')
```

[image]